# Does Doctrine represented a missing relation only with `NULL`?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am learning to use Doctrine on Symfony 5.4.

My understanding is that if you have an entity with a nullable `ManyToOne` relation

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="tblCustomer")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CustomerRepository::class)
 */
class Customer implements \JsonSerializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="customers", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true, name="id_user_default", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $dev_user;
}
```

on a insert without specifying something for `dev_user` relation, Doctrine try to run a query like

```sql
INSERT INTO tblCustomer (id_user_default) VALUES (NULL);
```

it seems that the "missing relation" is always represented with null. Am I right? Or for example I can make Doctrine set `0` for a missing relation, running then the query

```sql
INSERT INTO tblCustomer (id_user_default) VALUES (0);
```

?

Comment: Well, `0` would be misleading. It would make it look like there is something with the id `0` (think of foreign keys as well).

Comment: @JulienB. you are right, but think about a context where your db already exists and the _missing relation_ is represented as `0` on the foreign key column...

Comment: Unfortunately it's not uncommon to see this sort of trick for legacy databases.  Doctrine does not (as far as I know) support this sort of thing.  Doctrine creates a foreign constraint (`ALTER TABLE customers ADD CONSTRAINT FK_62534E2189F9CCBC FOREIGN KEY (dev_user_id) REFERENCES users (id);` which I am guessing your legacy database does not have.  If you are lucky you might actually have a fake user with an id of 0.  In which case you can remove the nullable=true and just make sure customer always has a user.